# <f:image> unwanted autoscale

Tags: typo3, extbase

In an extbase extension i want display images in the original imagesize. To have atomatic "width" and "height" i use  in the template

```
<f:image src="{/path/xy.png}" alt="{imagetext}" />
```

But it doesnt work like i expected. Typo3 make a resize over this images so they are stretched. I have no idea why and cant find something about in the i-net. Do someone know how i can force Typo to use the original image-size? I could use a normal IMG tag, but then i have no width and height in the markup. And yes, it would not hard to write an own ViewHelper for this, but i cant believe that it could be nessecary.

I apologize for the bad english and thank you for the answer.

Comment: I forgot to write in my first post: its a Typo3 6.0.5, perhaps this make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

In the install tool under "All Configuration" is the option: [im_noScaleUp]. You could try to set this.

Greetings

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found this option too and tried it, but it had no effect. 
I have used normal IMG-tags now, but im still interested for the reason of this curious scaling.

Comment: Very odd, what is the original width and height und what does typo put into the width height attributes?

Comment: Have you exchanged the picture previously? Because I encountered this bug myself lately: http://forge.typo3.org/issues/44105
Maybe you uploaded an smaller image and the old image width is somehow cached!